# SlideOverKit : A value of type 'SlideMenuView' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'IList'

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, cross-platform

I am implementing [BottomSheet](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/5d4e2cafbd00a82be79092c9b49c9f6f4e5462f9/687474703a2f2f7777772e78616d2d636f6e73756c74696e672e636f6d2f736c6964656f7665726b69742d78616d6172696e2d666f726d732f696d672f706f7274666f6c696f2f536c69646555704d656e752d694f532e676966) in `Xamarin.forms` with the help of [SlideOverKit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SlideOverKit/) library available in NuGet Gallery. I have referred their sample available on [GitHub](https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/SlideOverKit). My implementation details are bellow

Implementation details:

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SmartApp.CustomControls"
        xmlns:y="clr-namespace:SlideOverKit;assembly=SlideOverKit"
        Title="Opportunities"
         x:Class="SmartApp.OpportunitiesPage">
   <TabbedPage.ToolbarItems>
       <!--Menu Item here-->
   </TabbedPage.ToolbarItems>
   <ContentPage Title="Tab 1" >
       <!--Tab 1 details here-->
   </ContentPage>
   <y:SlideMenuView >
       <!--Tab 2 details here-->
   </y:SlideMenuView>
</TabbedPage>
```

In the above implementation I am facing on compile time error which is "A value of type 'SlideMenuView' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'IList'", also `y:SlideMenuView` not having support for `Title` attribute which is another issue. How can I resolve this issue? please help.

Answer (score 0):

The `SlideMenuView` must be placed within a `MenuContainerPage` instead of a `ContentPage`.

See their sample [in c#](https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/SlideOverKit/blob/master/SlideOverKitMoreSamples/SlideOverKit.Sample/Pages/SlideUpMenuPage.cs). The same can also be done in XAML:
Simply replace your `ContentPage` with a `y:MenuContainerPage` or create a custom page that inherits from `MenuContainerPage` and use that as parent page.

This information can also be found on [their website](https://www.xam-consulting.com/slideoverkit-xamarin-forms/):

> **Inherit**
>   The page which contains SlideMenuView must inherit from
>   MenuContainerPage or IMenuContainerPage. Your page can inherit from
>   MenuContainerPage, so that you can just set SlideMenuView property and
>   it will get work.
>
> If your page need to inherit from other base pages in your solution,
>   you must implement IMenuContainerPage interface and you need to create
>   the renderer pages for each platforms. It won't too hard, just copy
>   codes from sample, you can follow the SlideDownMenuPage page in sample
>   code to do this.